# location.reload() doesn't work on remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

I have a javascript animation which uses delay() and setInterval() functions. Everything works fine but animation elements become crazy when user opens another browser tab and goes back to the previous tab.

As a solution I need to reload the page each time a user is visited the animation tab again and it seems the solution is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

But I see that reloading page works only on localhost. The same code doesn't work on remote server i.e. page is not reloaded by revisiting the page.

Here is the code:

```
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (!document[hidden]) {location.reload();}
};

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Comment: Maybe the browser is caching the page, so reloading doesn't do anything.

Comment: Reloading a page just to handle an animation issue?! You should read: [what-is-the-xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  At least, if this animation is handled using jQuery, then pause/renable  it instead, but don't reload page

Comment: @Barmar, caching or not, the animation should start from the beginning if page is reloaded.

Comment: you can try window.location.reload(true);

Comment: @A.Wolff, my question is not about animation issue, but about location.reload() issue. Animation is just a reason for reloading.

Comment: @VishalJ, I tried `location.reload(true)` - without success.

Comment: @bonaca Ya, i understood it. I was just saying this is most probably a bad workaround to reload a full page just to handle some animation. If instead you ask question regarding your animation issue, i guess there is better to do. And anyway your code should work so you still have other issue

Comment: @A.Wolff - I see your point but it is very complicated to solve animation issue. All time functions are totally messed during absence from the tab. It is impossible to track them.I think reload the page is the simplest solution. Have you any idea what could be the solution on the animation level?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain, but it seems that soluton is

```
location.href = location.href;
```

instead of

```
location.reload();
```

The page is reloaded on local and remote server.