# Ajax & Session Variables? Worksafe Filter (selective image hiding)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, session-variables

I'm building a photography portfolio. Some of my images have nudity, so I want to hide those by default until the user clicks a "Toggle Worksafe Mode" button.

I can do it with a standard `form` `post` (and sessions), but that causes "confirm form resubmission" errors when the user `back`s or `reload`s. I'm trying to figure out an `AJAX` `post` instead to avoid that.

**UPDATE: This is the working code. Please note that this does NOT work with the "slim" jQuery distro; that's one of the main reasons I was having trouble.**

*Image Index Page:*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] {
        $_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] = 1;
    }
?>
<!-- other page content -->
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- other page content -->
<button type="button" id="Worksafe_Button" name="Worksafe_Button">
    Toggle Worksafe Mode
</button>
<script>
    $('#Worksafe_Button').click(function() {
        $.post("worksafe_mode_toggle.php")
            .done(function(data) {
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- other page content -->
<?php
$Connection = Connect();
$query = mysqli_query($Connection, 'SELECT uri, name, nsfw FROM images ORDER BY uri');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image)) {
    if ($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] == 1 && $row['nsfw'] == 1) {
        echo 'If you are over 18, toggle Worksafe Mode to view this image';
    }
    else {
        echo '<img alt="'.$row['title'].'" src="../'.$row['uri'].'/s.jpg" srcset="../'.$row['uri'].'/m.jpg 2x">';
    }
}
?>
```

*worksafe_mode_script:*

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] = 0;
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think ajax is a good approach in your case.

I might do something like display a page of SFW images as the default, along with the toggle button.

When they click the button it triggers an ajax request to the back-end that sets/un-sets the session value in `toggleWorksafe.php`. Finally it triggers a page refresh.

During the page refresh the PHP code checks whether the session variable is set and shows either the filtered or unfiltered set of images, and changes the button's text to match.

**To implement:**

Include jQuery in the `<head>` section (jQuery simplifies the ajax call):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'])) {
        $_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] = 'yes';
    }
  ?>

  <button id="workSafe" type="button" name="Worksafe_Toggle_Button">
  <?php 
    if ($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] == 'no') {
      echo 'Hide NSFW images';
    }
    else {
      echo 'Include NSFW images';
    }
  ?>
  </button>

  <!-- display safe images by default -->
  <?php 
    if ($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] == 'no') {
      echo '<br/><br/>Showing NSFW images';
    }
    else {
      echo '<br/><br/>Showing safe images only';
    }
  ?>

  <!-- any other page content here -->

  <script>
    $('#workSafe').click(function() {

      // ajax request to page toggling session value
      $.post("/toggleWorksafe.php")
        .done(function(data) {
          window.location.href = window.location.href; // trigger a page refresh
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**toggleWorksafe.php**:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] == 'yes') {
            $_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] = 'no';
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] = 'yes';
        }
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] = 'yes';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I had in mind. It's not quite working, though. I fixed minor errors (duplicated `foreach` conditions and ommited `session_start()`). I wasn't sure if "toggleWorksafe.php" as you have it was right or if it needed to mention the `$_POST` variable created by the click event. I edited the question with updated code from your ideas and I'd appreciate if you took another look.

Comment: Also be wary of `window.location.reload()`, it needs to refresh from the server not the browser's cache. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41042549/1544886

Comment: I've downloaded XAMPP, tested, and fixed the code in my answer. It now works correctly as written.  Whether "worksafe mode" should be set or not is determined entirely in back-end, so there's no point in passing any data to `toggleWorksafe.php`, just make the ajax call as I have above. Also do note the issue I mentioned when using `location.reload()`, better to stick with what I've used unless you find a specific use-case.  Finally,  note that you were missing a couple of closing brackets at the start of your code - `if (!isset($_SESSION['Worksafe_Mode'] {`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort!! This works perfectly for me now. In addition to typos I had and other stuff, it turns out the main problem was that this won't work with the "slim" jQuery distro I was using.

Answer (score 2):

there are a couple of ways to do this and it related to how you **hide** or **load** you images.

## 1. simple method

if you don't care about the user's age, and just need to toggle, then you can do it with just a js variable, a cookie, and two version of link. with this, you don't **hide** images, but **loads** them. the filtering is done in the server, where you can use database query or a simple folder separation. for example:

```
var nsfw = read_cookie('nsfw', false); // not an actual js function, search for how to read cookie in js --- read cookie value, default to false

function loadImage(nsfw){
    if (nsfw){
        $.get('nsfw-image-list-url', function(resp){
            // the url should return a json with list of image urls
            var list = resp;  // jQuery automatically parse json with the right MIME
            list.forEach(function(val){
                // insert image to page
                $('#container').append('<img src="' + val + '/>');
            });
        });
    } else {
        $.get('sfw-image-list-url', function(resp){
            // the url should return a json with list of image urls
            var list = resp;  // jQuery automatically parse json with the right MIME
            list.forEach(function(val){
                // insert image to page
                $('#container').append('<img src="' + val + '/>');
            });
        });
    }
}
```

and in you button click event:

```
nsfw = !nsfw;
// clear the image first if needed
$('#container').empty();
loadImage(nsfw);
```

## 2. another simple method, but not as simple as the #1

you can also do it with only one link that returns a list of images with the type of it, such as nsfw or other things.

note: this method still uses cookie

for example the returned list is like this:

```
[
    {"url": "some-image-1.jpg", "nsfw": "true"}, 
    {"url": "some-image-2.jpg", "nsfw": "false"}, 
    {"url": "some-image-3.jpg", "nsfw": "true"}, 
    {"url": "some-image-4.jpg", "nsfw": "false"}, 
    {"url": "some-image-5.jpg", "nsfw": "false"}, 
    {"url": "some-image-6.jpg", "nsfw": "true"}
]
```

then you just render it when the conditions are met.

```
function renderImage(nsfw){
    $.get('image-list-url', function(resp){
        list.forEach(function(val, key){
            if (nsfw || !val.nsfw){
                $('#container').append('<img src="' + val.url + '/>');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

## and many other methods that are too long to explain, such as using Angular, React, or Vue

still uses cookie for between reloads or backs, and does not regard user's age.

## as for the session based approach, you only need that if you need to verify your users age

that is if you have a membership functionality with DOB (date of birth) data in your site, if so, you can use @KScandrett 's answer

Answer (score 0):

**Confirm form resubmission** happens because you do not perform a redirect after a successful form submission.

Take a look at this wiki page to see how to do it right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get